# The value Address of Entry Point different in PE Explorer and UltraEdit

Tags: exe, portable-executable, virus, ultraedit

I wrote a basic `helloworld.exe` with C with the simple line `printf("helloworld!\n");`

Then I used UltraEdit to view the bytes of the EXE file and used also PE Explorer to see the header values. When it comes to **Address of Entry Point**, PE Explorer displays `0x004012c0`.

```
Magic                            010Bh   PE32
Linker Version                   1902h   2.25
Size of Code                 00008000h
Size of Initialized Data     0000B000h
Size of Uninitialized Data   00000C00h
Address of Entry Point       004012C0h
Base of Code                 00001000h
Base of Data                 00009000h
Image Base                   00400000h
```

But in UltraEdit I see `0x000012c0` after counting 16 bytes after magic `0x010B`.

```
3F 02 00 00 E0 00 07 03 0B 01 02 19 00 80 00 00
00 B0 00 00 00 0C 00 00 C0 12 00 00 00 10 00 00
00 90 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 10 00 00 00 02 00 00
04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 10 01 00 00 04 00 00 91 F6 00 00 03 00 00 00
00 00 20 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 10 00 00
00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 E0 00 00 C0 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply read about [*IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx) structure

> **AddressOfEntryPoint**
>
> A pointer to the entry point function, **relative** to the image base
>   address. For executable files, this is the starting address. For
>   device drivers, this is the address of the initialization function.
>   The entry point function is optional for DLLs. When no entry point is
>   present, this member is zero.

so **absolute** address of `EntryPoint` is `AddressOfEntryPoint ? ImageBase + AddressOfEntryPoint : 0`

in your case `AddressOfEntryPoint == 12c0` and `ImageBase == 400000`

as result absolute address of `EntryPoint` is `12c0+400000==4012c0`